# Installing PHP 5.5.6: Can't start php-cgi.exe - MSVCR110.dll is missing

Tags: php, windows-7, web-server, iis-7, php53

I'm trying to update from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 after downloading the last version from [here](http://windows.php.net/download/) and I'm having this error:

> Can't start php-cgi.exe - MSVCR110.dll is missing

I've read that I need to install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Is that right?

Can't I just download the `.dll` file? Why should I install VS just to work with PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't I just download the .dll file?

No this is not going to work. You need to install the entire C++ Redistributable package.

(Even if just dropping that one dll into the app directory or into System32 *did* technically work, I'd still recommend installing the Redistributable package because it's easier to account for what is installed  on the computer that way, etc.)

> Why should I install VS just to work with PHP?

You're not installing Visual Studio. You're just installing a small package that includes support binaries needed to run applications that were built with Visual Studio.